# ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 14.04 on Raspberry Pi 2.
I installed rpi.gpio

```
$sudo pip3 install RPi.GPIO 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun ros_start led_blink.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/ros_start/scripts/led_blink.py", line6, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO
```

Please tell me the solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221202/importerror:-no-module-named-rpi.gpio/) by [Kazuki Kadonaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/23157/kazuki-kadonaka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik ROS doesn't use Python 3, but Python 2. You'll have to install `RPi.GPIO` for Python 2 (if possible).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0